# Regex to match quotes in CSV inside fields

Tags: regex, linux, pcre

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match double-quotes inside CSV fields (and replace them with escaped double-quotes, but the replacement part is easy).

So I want

```
"field1","field2" -> "field1","field2"
"field1","fie"ld2" -> "field1","fie""ld2"
```

I'm using `(?<!;)"(?!;)` as my matching expression, which *nearly* works - but it doesn't handle the quote at the start or the end of the line. I need something like either `(?<![;$])"(?![;^])` which doesn't work because the exact `$` and `^` characters are matched here - or `(?<!(;|$))"(?!(;|^))` which also doesn't work because a negative lookbehind can't be variable length.

What's the correct way of doing this please?

Comment: Why capture the lookaround patterns? `(?<!;|^)"(?!;|$)` works. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8vbd5/1). Better, use `(?<=[^;])"(?=[^;])` that does not even use the alternation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCRE regex engine does not allow capturing groups with alternation operator inside them inside a lookbehind.

You can re-phrase the regex you tried as

```php
(?<!;|^)"(?!;|$)
(?<=[^;])"(?=[^;])
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8vbd5/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8vbd5/2).

The `(?<!;|^)"(?!;|$)` pattern matches a `"` char that is not at the start of string and not immediately preceded with a `;` char (due to `(?<!;|^)`) and that is not immediately followed with a `;` char and not at the end of string (see `(?!;|$)`).

The `(?<=[^;])"(?=[^;])` regex matches a `"` that is immediately preceded with a char other than a `;` (so, no start of string position is allowed) and that is followed with a char other than a `;` (no end of string position allowed).